# ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework connection string and context not works while creating database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have some problems with my ASP.NET MVC project, using Entity Framework. The problem is about connection strings (I searched it on web but not works yet)

These are my scenarios:

The ASP.NET MVC project has a class called `DbData` extending `DbContext`. A controller calls a new instance of this class and call `SaveChanges` to create the database. I'm having problem with database creation.

1. If I run without specific configuration and inspect context instance, I get this exception

   > Invalid operation. The connection is closed

   The data source is `.\SQLEXPRESS` by dafault. Result cannot create the database
2. If I try to use a connection string with a specific SQL Server database with name setting in `web.config` and name in `DbData : base("name = dbconn")`, I get an error that "dbconn" doesn't exist in `web.config`.

the code:

```
public class DbData : DbContext
{
    public DbData()
        //: base("Name=dbconn")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Info> infos {get;set;}
}
```

this is the web config ( trying to use a custom connection string )

```
<add name="dbconn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=MYPC\SQL2012;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Database=MvcDB;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
```

EntityFramework section into web.config:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
```

I'm going crazy. Help me please.  Thanks

Comment: can you post your config settings for  <entityFramework>

Comment: Your Web.Config should have an <entityFramework> section. If it doesn't than you need to add/configure it. If you do have one then please post it so that we can help you.

Comment: Try `: base("dbconn")`  instead of `: base("name = dbconn")`

Comment: Now it works! I created a new project and works. Both approach are fine, Don't know why first project failed on EF side. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your Default LocalDB  (sqlExpress in your case) then your  tag in the   should look the following:

```
 <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="localdbinstancename" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

If you are wanting to use a specific database server (with a configured connection string) your config file will look something like:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" >
      <parameters>
            <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
         </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

***The important difference is the connectionfactory reference in the  tag.**

*The parameter tag may not be necessary depending on how the connection string is specified.